# python queue thread performance

Tags: python

I have 2 questions regarding thread and queue in python.

1. What does `max_size` arg do in `queue.Queue()`?
2. Are there any performance improvement depending on the # of threads(`num_worker_threads`)? I can't find any improvements on it. 
   -> If there's no improvements depending on the # of threads, why do we need this?

```python
import time 
import queue
import threading

num_worker_threads = 10

store = []
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        store.append(item)
        q.task_done()


start = time.time()        
q = queue.Queue() # what does max_size do in queue?
threads = []
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for item in range(1000000):
    q.put(item)

# block until all tasks are done
q.join()

# stop workers
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    q.put(None)
for t in threads:
    t.join()
end = time.time()

print('running time: {}'.format(end - start))
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the max size on a queue in order to provide a throttling mechanism for your workers. Assuming you have X producers and Y consumers using the same queue, if any of the consumers throws a `Queue.Full` exception, you can use this as a signal to slow down on producing.

In your case, since work doesn't actually do anything computationally expensive (just appends to a list, in an unsafe manner i might add), and you only have 1 producer and 10 consumers, the queue will most likely always be empty and instead the consumers are idling (and would throw a `Queue.Empty` exception if the get method had a timeout attached.

As a side note, in order to figure out which of the consumer and producers are idling, you should use the `timeout` parameter for both the `put` and `get` methods of the queue

Comment: I can't fully understand the usage of queue and thread. 
Please check if i understood right.  

borrowing your words from above code:  

**consumer** :  10 queues  

**producer** : `for item in range(1000000)` 

**max_size** : somewhat qty to prevent throttling event. 

Can I use more than one producer when i load a binary file containing image or text related data?

Comment: Can't i use HTML in comment?

Comment: Correct. The consumers in your case are the 10 threads. The producer is the main thread that's running the for loop. If you had launched more threads that use `Queue.put`, then you would have multiple consumers

Comment: I'm learning machine learning and i think i've never seen using multiple **producers** for a single file yet. Is it normal and non-critical to performance not using multiple **producers** for a single file?

Comment: no, a file per produces sounds about right, but this is already outside of the question scope.